# Windows XP alternatives to Wireless Zero Configuration

Tags: wifi, windows-xp, configuration-management, wireless

The manufacturer built-in wireless configuration tool on my laptop absolutely stinks:  no priority support and it switches between networks like crazy.

I've been using Windows' Wireless Zero Configuration tool, but it's pretty cumbersome.

Some features I'd expect in a good tool:

- switch between networks quickly (my friend's just has a system tray menu)
- actually *stay connected* to the network I say to
- do all that in a way that doesn't force me to open task manager :-(

Does there exist any kind of wireless network configuration tool for Windows XP?